# What is the difference between the work of JTAPI and CCXML ? Why do we need JTAPI if CCXML is already there?

Tags: jtapi, ccxml

What is the difference between the work of JTAPI and CCXML ? Why do we need JTAPI if CCXML is already there ??

Answer (score 0):

These are two different mechanisms used in different scenarios.

**JTAPI** is a Java interface, and designed for Computer-Telephony-Integration (CTI). The PABX vendor still need to provide the implementation to this interface as it applies to it's environment. With JTAPI the Java application would normally connect to the CTI component of the PABX.

In addition to the normal telephony functions like making calls, transferring calls etc, JTAPI can also be used to listen for events in the PABX related to certain calls. For example, recording systems, they need to listen for incoming calls to specific groups of telephones and record the audio streams, and stop recording when the call is dropped, or follow the call as it is transferred.

**CCXML** will more likely be used together with VoiceXML on IVR or self service systems. This will allow the self service platform to make outbound calls.

Some PABX vendors might use JTAPI to implement outbound dialer systems, some would use CCXML. This really depends on the internal architecture of the PABX system, as the components implementing JTAPI and CCXML respectively are intended to fulfill two different requirements, and not all environment/customers will have access to one or the other.